# What is the angle between hour's hand and minute's hand if the time is $10:10:35$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the angle between hour's hand and minute's hand if the time is $10:10:35$ ?
>   I try to apply the following formula 
>   $$
> \theta = |30H - 5.5M|
> $$
>   $$
> 180 = 30H - 5.5M ~~~~~~~\mbox{or}~~~~~~~ -180 = 30H-5.5M
> $$
>   $$
> M = \frac{30H - 180}{5.5} ~~~~~~~\mbox{or}~~~~~~~ M = \frac{30H+180}{5.5}
> $$

But this formula doesn't take in consideration the hand of seconds,  which indeed affect the answer?

Comment: I've never seen that formula before, but if that is true for any minute, then just take $M=127/12$ and solve accordingly.

Comment: well seconds are decimals of minutes I guess 0.50 minute is 30seconds

Comment: Use your formula with $M=10+\dfrac{35}{60}$! gives $118^\circ.208$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between the XII hour mark on the clock and the hour's hand is $$\frac{10}{12}+\frac{10}{12\cdot 60}+\frac{35}{12\cdot 60 \cdot 60}=\frac{7327}{8640}$$ of the full angle.

The angle between the XII hour mark on the clock and the minute's hand is $$\frac{10}{60}+\frac{35}{60\cdot 60}=\frac{127}{720}$$
of the full angle.

Thus the angle between the hour's hand and minute's hand is 
$$\left|\frac{7327}{8640}-\frac{127}{720}\right|=\frac{5803}{8640}$$
of the full angle, which is $\frac{5803}{8640} \cdot 360^\circ = 241\frac{19}{24}^\circ$.

The convex angle between the hands is therefore 
$$360^\circ - 241\frac{19}{24}^\circ = \frac{2837}{24}^\circ \approx 118.208333^\circ.$$

Comment: Again a reflex angle.  Get the proper angle by subtracting from a full revolution.

Comment: First to properly subtract from a full revolution to get the convex angle +1.

Answer (score 1):

$10:10:35$ is $36635$ seconds after midnight so the angle of the hour handle is $2 \pi \frac{36635}{43200} \approx 5.33$, since there are $43200$ seconds in $12$ hours.

$10:10:35$ is $635$ seconds since the hour handle was at the starting position. An hour has $3600$ seconds, so the minute handle makes an angle of $2 \pi \frac{635}{3600} \approx 1.11$

You then sustract them and obtain that the angle between them was $4.22$

Comment: Not 4.22 radians. That is a reflex angle, they want the "proper" angle so subtract the reflex angle from $2\pi$.